# Problems a multidimensional array as part of a std::pair

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, std-pair

I have a problem with forming a std::pair which I do not understand, maybe someone can explain it to me.

I have a `typedef uint16_t Cursor_matrix[1][2];`

In the following part of the program, I assign my *Cursor_matrix* variables to values, which I then want to connect to a std::string using a std::pair.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

typedef uint16_t Cursor_matrix[1][2];

int main()
{
    Cursor_matrix pos;
    pos[0][0] = 1;
    pos[0][1] = 2;

    std::string str = "hello";
    std::pair<Cursor_matrix, std::string> pos_text;

    pos_text = std::make_pair(pos, str);
    return 0;
}
```

*1: Here I get the following error message from the compiler (gcc 4,7,3)

```
source>:22:33: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::pair<short unsigned int [1][2], std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' and 'std::pair<short unsigned int (*)[2], std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >')
```

The error message tells me, that the size of my Cursos_matrix is not known. However, this already exists as "pos".

SOLUTION:

**Dont use native arrays with managed objects**

```
using Cursor_matrix = std::array<std::array<uint16_t,2>, 1>;

int main()
{
    Cursor_matrix pos;
    pos[0][0] = 1;
    pos[0][1] = 2;

    std::string str = "hello";

    std::pair<Cursor_matrix, std::string> pos_text;

    pos_text = std::make_pair(pos, str);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to WhozCraig!

Comment: The *verbtim* error message should be telling you more than that. And a [mcve] for this would look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/rhvc7EKe3). The short version, however, is that native arrays are not assignable in lvalue contexts (and that includes your native array of native array of `uint16_t`). If you want assignability you need to shroud it in a structure or object context. Ex: instead of your typedef, `using Cursor_matrix = std::array<std::array<uint16_t,2>, 1>;` should make all the code you presented magically work.

Comment: Ok thanks a very lot!  So usually object classes which derive STL elements need ilterators etc. ? 
Thanks for the link to the Compiler Explorer I will revise my question accordingly.